# Spring session-scoped bean in TestNG test?

Tags: spring, testng, spring-test

As of Spring 3.2, you can have request-scoped and session-scoped beans in your tests, that can be read [in the Spring reference manual, section 11.3.5](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-web-scoped-beans).

For example:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class Test1
{
    @Autowired
    private MySessionBean state;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(state.toString());
    }
}
```

The above works. However, trying to adjust this to TestNG:

```java
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
public class Test2 extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests
{
    @Autowired
    private MySessionBean state;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(state.toString());
    }
}
```

This will throw an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are
>   you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request,
>   or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread?

Am I doing something wrong or is testing with session-scoped beans only supported with JUnit and not TestNG?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not on Spring Framework 3.2.7 or later, this won't work by default.

See [SPR-11340](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11340) for details.

As a work-around, you can declare your test class as follows

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("/applicationContext.xml")
@TestExecutionListeners({
  ServletTestExecutionListener.class,
  DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
  DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class
})
public class Test2 extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests { /* ... */ }
```

Regards,

Sam

Comment: Any idea how to get this to work for wire mock server?